# Counting seconds doesn't work

Tags: c, counting, seconds

Okay, so I wrote this code and it should to my knowledge output HMS time, but it only outputs 00:00:00 WAY longer than a second. I have not tried to wait longer than a couple of hours to see if it changes.
I know it's not a hardware problem because my lcd works perfectly fine and
I do not have anything else connected to my arduino.
If you want to know, I have tried to put the "_time" function "over" loop.

This is the code:

```
#include <LiquidCrystal.h>
LiquidCrystal lcd(12, 11, 5, 4, 3, 2);

int hour;
int minute;
int seconds = -1;
boolean printed = false;
boolean secCounted = false;
unsigned long nextMillis = 1000;

void setup() {
  lcd.begin(16, 2);
}

 void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  if(currentMillis = nextMillis) _time(), nextMillis += 1000;
 }

void _time(){

                                    seconds += 1;
  if(seconds == 60)                 seconds = 0, minute += 1;
  if(minute == 60 && hour <= 12)    minute = 0, hour += 1; 

  if(printed == false){
  if(hour == 0)                     lcd.print("00");
  if(hour != 0 && hour < 10)       {lcd.print("0");
                                    lcd.print(hour);}
  if(hour > 9)                      lcd.print(hour);
                                    lcd.print(":"); 
  if(minute == 0)                   lcd.print("00");
  if(minute != 0 && minute < 10)   {lcd.print("0");
                                    lcd.print(minute);}
  if(minute > 9)                    lcd.print(minute);
                                    lcd.print(":");
  if(seconds == 0)                  lcd.print("00");
  if(seconds != 0 && seconds < 10) {lcd.print("0");
                                    lcd.print(seconds);}
  if(seconds > 9)                   lcd.print(seconds);
  printed = true;
  }
}
```

Comment: It might help if you added a tag for the programming language ([tag:c]?)

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
if(currentMillis = nextMillis) // here is nextMillis is assigned to currentMillis
```

on

```
 if(currentMillis == nextMillis) // here is nextMillis is compared with currentMillis on equality
```

Comment: Thanks! Also i forgot two things:  1) to make "printed" false, 2) to clear lcd.